# Open Stream and CancellationException causes Thread lock

Tags: java, android, multithreading, exception, memory-leaks

I have a rather complex application that I'm trying to create for an android phone. I have a class that uses the Java Process Builder and some private classes to read from both the input and output streams.

At times when the IP I'm trying to ping does not respond the thread locks due to the process getting stuck, the executor service decides after 2 minutes to shutdown. This avoids the entire application locking but the two streams never close and the threads for the streams stay open.

Any idea how to kill the stream threads?

```
class StreamGobbler extends Thread {
    InputStream is;
    String type;

    StreamGobbler(InputStream is, String type) {
        this.is = is;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void run() {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        try {

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(type + ">" + line); 
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LogWriter.getInstance().writeToLogFile(e);
        }finally{

            try {
                if(is != null){
                    is.close();
                }
                if(isr != null){
                    isr.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LogWriter.getInstance().writeToLogFile(e);
            }
        }
    }

    public void kill() {

        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}



public class PingRunner implements Callable<Double>{

private String pingVal;
private int exitVal;
private double laten;
private String ipAddress;

public PingRunner(String ipAddress) {
    pingVal = "";
    exitVal = -1;
    laten = -1;
    this.ipAddress = ipAddress;
}

@Override
public Double call() throws Exception {

    List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
    commands.add("ping");
    commands.add("-c");
    commands.add("5");
    commands.add(ipAddress);
    try {
        this.doCommand(commands);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LogWriter.getInstance().writeToLogFile(e);
    }

    return laten;
}

    private void doCommand(List<String> command) throws IOException{

    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    Process process = pb.start();

    // any error message?
    StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new StreamGobbler(
            process.getErrorStream(), "ERROR");

    // any output?
    OutputStreamGobbler outputGobbler = new OutputStreamGobbler(
            process.getInputStream(), "OUTPUT");

    // kick them off
    errorGobbler.start();
    outputGobbler.start();

    // read the output from the command
    try {
        exitVal = process.waitFor();
        //Sleep for 10 secs to try to clear the buffer
        Thread.sleep(10000);

        //pingVal = echo.toString();
        if(exitVal == 0 && !pingVal.isEmpty()){
            //System.out.println("PING STATS: "+pingVal);
            try{
            pingVal = pingVal.substring(pingVal.lastIndexOf("rtt min/avg/max/mdev"));
            pingVal = pingVal.substring(23);
            pingVal = pingVal.substring(pingVal.indexOf("/")+1);
            laten = Double.parseDouble(pingVal.substring(0,pingVal.indexOf("/")));
            }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                System.out.println("PING VAL: "+ pingVal);
                LogWriter.getInstance().writeToLogFile(e);
            }
        }


    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        LogWriter.getInstance().writeToLogFile(e);
        errorGobbler.kill();
        outputGobbler.kill();
    }finally{
        errorGobbler = null;
        outputGobbler = null;
    }
    System.out.println("ExitValue: " + exitVal);
}
```

In my main class I have this method:

```
protected void ping() {
    laten = -1;
    serverIP = serverIPs.get(testIndex % 3);

    PingRunner pRunner = new PingRunner(serverIP);

    Set<Callable<Double>> runner = new HashSet<Callable<Double>>();
    runner.add(pRunner);

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    try {
        laten = executor.submit(pRunner).get(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        executor.shutdown();

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        LogWriter.getInstance().writeToLogFile(e);
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        LogWriter.getInstance().writeToLogFile(e);
    } catch (CancellationException e) {
        pRunner.kill();
        executor.shutdown();
        LogWriter.getInstance().writeToLogFile(e);
        LogWriter.getInstance().writeToLogFile(
                "ERROR: Unable to ping server: " + serverIP);
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        pRunner.kill();
        executor.shutdown();
        LogWriter.getInstance().writeToLogFile(e);
        LogWriter.getInstance().writeToLogFile(
                "ERROR: Unable to ping server: " + serverIP);
    } finally {
        executor = null;
        System.gc();
    }
```

Comment: Any way your can whittle the code down?  Right now this is just too localized.

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea how to kill the stream threads?

Not sure what is going on but one bug I see is:

```
public void kill() {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

That is interrupting the *caller* thread, not the gobbler thread.  That should be:

```
public void kill() {
    // kill the gobbler thread
    interrupt();
}
```

This is true since the `StreamGobbler` extends `Thread`.  As always, it is recommended that you `implements Runnable` and then have a `private Thread field` if necessary.  Then you would do something like `thread.interrupt();`.

Also, you are not closing your streams correctly.  Typically, when I wrap one stream in another, I set the wrapped stream to be `null`.  Also, you are not closing the `br` `BufferedReader`.  The code should be:

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
is = null;
BufferedReader br = null;
try {
    br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    isr = null;
    String line = null;
    ...
} finally {
    // IOException catches not listed
    if(br != null){
        br.close();
    }
    if(isr != null){
        isr.close();
    }
    if(is != null){
        is.close();
    }
}
```

I'm a big fan of the `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils` package that has the `closeQuietly(...)` method that turns the finally block into:

```
IOUtils.closeQuietly(br);
IOUtils.closeQuietly(isr);
IOUtils.closeQuietly(is);
```

Comment: I tried this, but when the executor throws an interrupt/cancellation exception and I try to kill the pingrunner and associated gobbler threads, the methods return, but the gobbler threads for the  never gets GC'ed, so I can only assume that interrupt isnt killing the threads.